# How to display multiple dropdown value on another html fields using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

1. I have few dropdown with text fields.
2. I want to get all those values and display on a button.
3. The only condition is that button should be generate upto 5 time.
   means -> if all the value of dropdown & text field are displaying on a button field so i want to generate another button and again i want to display my value on that by clicking on generate button.
   Here is my code for reference.

```js
$('#left_indicator').on('change', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    /* Act on the event */
    if ($(this).val()=='sma') {
      $("#left_period_guider").html('(period,offset)');
    }else if ($(this).val()=='ema') {
      $("#left_period_guider").html('(close,period,offset)');
    }
    
  });
  $('#right_indicator').on('change', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    /* Act on the event */
    if ($(this).val()=='sma') {
      $("#right_period_guider").html('(period,offset)');
    }else if ($(this).val()=='ema') {
      $("#right_period_guider").html('(close,period,offset)');
    }
    
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!-- jQuery library -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <select name="left_indicator" id="left_indicator">
      <option>select</option>
      <option value="sma">sma</option>
      <option value="ema">ema</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="left_PeriodAndOffset" id="left_PeriodAndOffset" placeholder="e.g (10.2)">
    <div id="left_period_guider"></div>
    <select name="comparator" id="comparator">
      <option>select</option>
      <option value="=">=</option>
      <option value="<"><</option>
    </select>


    <select name="right_indicator" id="right_indicator">
      <option>select</option>
      <option value="sma">sma</option>
      <option value="ema">ema</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="right_PeriodAndOffset" id="right_PeriodAndOffset" placeholder="e.g (10.2)">
    <div id="right_period_guider"></div>

    <button type="button" id="generateButton" name="generateButton">click to generate button upto 5 with remove button</button>
    <hr>

    This button should generate by clicking above the button with the all field provided values.
    example : sma(10.2) < ema(3.2)
    <button type="button" id="generated1" name="generated1" value="">value will display here</button>
    <button type="button" id="removethis" name="removethis">removethis</button>
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see here,
I'm just expecting the solution like all the dropdown and text field value should display on a button and generate the button so i can do the same strategies on another button upto 5 time.
so value should display on each generated button like. sma(10.2) < ema(3.2).

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, only buttons would be generated not the form... And the dynamically added remove' button would remove only it's associated dynamic button right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code would do the Job !

To perform better validation, I added a class name 'chk' to check all input fields.
This would be used to validate and generate the buttons' data. 
Notice that I also added an empty value property to your select boxes, that's required for this code.

```js
var data='';
var btnid=0;
function generateBtn(data){
    btnid++;
    var btns='<button type="button" id="generated'+btnid+'" name="generated'+btnid+'" value="" data-id="'+btnid+'">'+data+'</button><button type="button" id="removethis" class="removethis" data-id="'+btnid+'">removethis</button>';
    $('#container').append(btns);
}
function check_inputs() {
    var i=0;
    //validation to check for empty inputs
    //Same loop used to generate valid Button' Data
    
    data='';
    //we reset Data
    $('.chk').each(function(){
        
        if( $(this).val() === "" ){
          $(this).css({'border-color':'red','border-size':'3px'}); 
        } else{
            $(this).css({'border-color':'green','border-size':'3px'});
            if($(this).is('input')){
                data+='('+$(this).val()+')';
            } else {
                data+=' '+$(this).val();
            }
            
            i++;
        }
    });
    if(i==$('.chk').length){
    //We gernerate the button
    generateBtn(data);
    } else{
        return;
    }
}

//Dynamically generated buttons are non-Dom, so we base selction on the parent container
//Data-id attribute is used to match targeted buttons
$("#container").on('click','.removethis', function() {
        $('button[data-id='+$(this).data('id')+']').remove();
});    
$("#generateButton").on('click', function() {  
    //Because we can remove buttons
    //We count generated buttons before generating more than 5
    if($("[id^=generated]").length<5){
    check_inputs();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <select name="left_indicator" id="left_indicator" class="chk">
      <option value="">select</option>
      <option value="sma">sma</option>
      <option value="ema">ema</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="left_PeriodAndOffset" id="left_PeriodAndOffset" placeholder="e.g (10.2)" class="chk">
    <div id="left_period_guider"></div>
    <select name="comparator" id="comparator" class="chk">
      <option value="">select</option>
      <option value="=">=</option>
      <option value="<"><</option>
    </select>


    <select name="right_indicator" id="right_indicator" class="chk">
      <option value="">select</option>
      <option value="sma">sma</option>
      <option value="ema">ema</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="right_PeriodAndOffset" id="right_PeriodAndOffset" placeholder="e.g (10.2)" class="chk">
    <div id="right_period_guider"></div>

    <button type="button" id="generateButton" name="generateButton">click to generate button upto 5 with remove button</button>
    <hr>
</div>
```

I commented the code, but I suggest you revise your HTML code for the small (Non standard) mistakes. Just to pay attention to What's unique and what's not!  I don't know if this is meant to be in `<form>` or not, repeating name property in buttons for example should be taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I'm not sure where to put the buttons, so I assumed to place it at the end of the document. To make it even simple I added a div at the end before the closing of the body.

```
<div id="displayButtons" style="display:block;">
```

Then you can add the following code in the script tag to achieve what you are looking for.

```
    var buttonCount = 0;
$('#generateButton').click(function () {
    if (buttonCount < 5) {
        // Get all values
        let left_indicator = $("#left_indicator").val();
        let left_PeriodAndOffset = $("#left_PeriodAndOffset").val();
        let comparator = $("#comparator").val();
        let right_indicator = $("#right_indicator").val();
        let right_PeriodAndOffset = $("#right_PeriodAndOffset").val();

        // Define Button to display
        let buttonText = left_indicator + " (" + left_PeriodAndOffset + ") " + comparator + " " + right_indicator + " (" + right_PeriodAndOffset + ")";
        let button = '<button id="' + buttonCount + '">' + buttonText + '</button>';

        // Display button inside Div
        $("#displayButtons").append(button);
        buttonCount++;
    } else {
        alert("Limit of 5 reached");
    }
})

$("#removethis").click(function () {
    if (buttonCount > 0) {
        $("#displayButtons > button:last-child").remove();
        buttonCount--;
    }
    else {
        alert("No more buttons to remove.");
    }

})
```

Another additional thing I would like to mention is ;

```
 $('#left_indicator').on('change', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    /* Act on the event */
    if ($(this).val() == 'sma') {
        $("#left_period_guider").text('(period,offset)');  <== I think you need to replace html with text to display what you require..
    } else if ($(this).val() == 'ema') {
        $("#left_period_guider").text('(close,period,offset)');
    }

});
```

I hope that's what you were looking for...

Complete working Code:

```js
var buttonCount = 0;
$('#generateButton').click(function () {
    if (buttonCount < 5) {
        // Get all values
        let left_indicator = $("#left_indicator").val();
        let left_PeriodAndOffset = $("#left_PeriodAndOffset").val();
        let comparator = $("#comparator").val();
        let right_indicator = $("#right_indicator").val();
        let right_PeriodAndOffset = $("#right_PeriodAndOffset").val();

        // Define Button to display
        let buttonText = left_indicator + " (" + left_PeriodAndOffset + ") " + comparator + " " + right_indicator + " (" + right_PeriodAndOffset + ")";
        let button = '<button id="' + buttonCount + '">' + buttonText + '</button>';

        // Display button inside Div
        $("#displayButtons").append(button);
        buttonCount++;
    } else {
        alert("Limit of 5 reached");
    }
})

$("#removethis").click(function () {
    if (buttonCount > 0) {
        $("#displayButtons > button:last-child").remove();
        buttonCount--;
    }
    else {
        alert("No more buttons to remove.");
    }

})

$('#left_indicator').on('change', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    /* Act on the event */
    if ($(this).val()=='sma') {
      $("#left_period_guider").text('(period,offset)');
    }else if ($(this).val()=='ema') {
      $("#left_period_guider").text('(close,period,offset)');
    }
    
  });
  $('#right_indicator').on('change', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    /* Act on the event */
    if ($(this).val()=='sma') {
      $("#right_period_guider").text('(period,offset)');
    }else if ($(this).val()=='ema') {
      $("#right_period_guider").text('(close,period,offset)');
    }
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="left_indicator" id="left_indicator">
      <option>select</option>
      <option value="sma">sma</option>
      <option value="ema">ema</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="left_PeriodAndOffset" id="left_PeriodAndOffset" placeholder="e.g (10.2)">
    <div id="left_period_guider"></div>
    <select name="comparator" id="comparator">
      <option>select</option>
      <option value="=">=</option>
      <option value="<"><</option>
    </select>


    <select name="right_indicator" id="right_indicator">
      <option>select</option>
      <option value="sma">sma</option>
      <option value="ema">ema</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="right_PeriodAndOffset" id="right_PeriodAndOffset" placeholder="e.g (10.2)">
    <div id="right_period_guider"></div>

    <button type="button" id="generateButton" name="generateButton">click to generate button upto 5 with remove button</button>
    <hr>

    This button should generate by clicking above the button with the all field provided values.
    example : sma(10.2) < ema(3.2)
    <button type="button" id="generated1" name="generated1" value="">value will display here</button>
    <button type="button" id="removethis" name="removethis">removethis</button>
    
</div>
<div id="displayButtons" style="display:block;">
```

Comment: hi, I have checked this but it is not working in my side. will you please try to make it snippet.